# Multiple Term search by following multiple users using Streaming API

Tags: python

I am trying to Retrieve multiple keyword term tweets by following specific group of users. Using the code below:

I have posted one more code before that regarding issues for value error: 
I figure it out somehow but again I am stuck because of this traceback

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.error import TweepError
consumer_key=('ABC'),
consumer_secret=('ABC'),
access_key=('ABC'),
access_secret=('ABC')
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api=tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):


        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source,)
        except Exception, e:
            print error
    #def filter(self, follow=None, track=None, async=False, locations=None):
        #self.parameters = {}
        #self.headers['Content-type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        #if self.running:
            #raise TweepError('Stream object already connected!')
        #self.url = '/%i/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length' % STREAM_VERSION
    def filter(self, follow=None,  track=None,  async=False,  locations=None):
        self.parameters = {}
        self.headers['Content-type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        if self.running:
            raise TweepError('Stream object already connected!')
        self.url = '/%i/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length' % STREAM_VERSION
        if obey:
            self.parameters['follow'] = ' '.join(map(str,  obey))
        if track:
            self.parameters['track'] = ' '.join(map(str,  track))
        if locations and len(locations) > 0:
            assert len(locations) % 4 == 0
            self.parameters['locations'] = ' '.join('%.2f' % l for l in locations)
            self.body = urllib.urlencode(self.parameters)
            self.parameters['delimited'] = 'length'
            self._start(async)
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return True 
streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)
list_users = ['17006157','59145948','157009365','16686144','68044757','33338729']#Some ids
list_terms = ['narendra modi','robotics']#Some terms
streaming_api.filter(follow=[list_users])
streaming_api.filter(track=[list_terms])
```

I am getting a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nytimes\26052014\Multiple term search with multiple addreses.py", line 49, in <module>
    streaming_api.filter(follow=[list_users])
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 296, in filter
    encoded_follow = [s.encode(encoding) for s in follow]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: *'list' object has no attribute 'encode'* what about this error don't you understand?

Comment: I did not understand the error Tim that is why I am asking for help..please post the solution for it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `list_users` here

```
list_users = ['17006157','59145948','157009365','16686144','68044757','33338729']
```

and then you pass it to `streaming_api.filter` like this

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=[list_users])
```

When the `streaming_api.filter` function is iterating over the value you pass as `follow`, it gives the error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

The reason for this is as follows

You call `streaming_api.filter` like this

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=[list_users])
```

Here

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=[list_users])
```

you are trying to pass your list as value for `follow`, however because you put `list_users` in enclosing `[]` you are creating a list in a list. Then `streaming_api.filter` iterates over `follow`, calling `.encode` on each entry as we see here

```
[s.encode(encoding) for s in follow]
```

But the entry `s` is a list while it should be a string.
That is because you accidentally created a list in a list like you can see above.

---

The solution is simple. Change

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=[list_users])
```

to

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=list_users)
```

To pass a list to a function, you can just specify the name. No need to enclose it in `[]`

Same applies to the last line. Change

```
streaming_api.filter(track=[list_terms])
```

to

```
streaming_api.filter(track=list_terms)
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Tim. I did the same as you mentioned above but now I am getting another traceback.

Comment: @SourabhChoudhary It might be better to address that new error in a new question because the error you posted is fixed with this answer

Comment: @SourabhChoudhary or is the issue small enough that we can fix it here?

Comment: Ok Tim sorry for inconvenience but I have posted the new traceback in the code asked above.

Comment: @SourabhChoudhary oh well that is an entirely different error, I suggest you ask a new question for that ;-)

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot I am just raising this within few minutes @Tim Castelijns

Comment: Thanks Tim I posted it. Waiting for the solutions.

Comment: @SourabhChoudhary can you accept this answer then? So we can close the question

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim. The problem with list objects solved.